# Job not running: 'No such file or directory' but the script exists

Tags: bash, jobs, sungridengine

I'm a bioinformatician, new in the community and quite new about working with bash-commands.

I recently encountered a very trivial error message but for me the issue is a bit complex to fix.

Briefly, when I launch a script with the `qsub` command (from the master node ) the job does not work and I find the following error message in the 'log' file:

> Fatal error: cannot open file
>   '/data/users/genethongandolfi/scripts/multi454.mse/multi454fasta.manip.r':
>   No such file or directory

This sounds quite strange for me since the path to the script file called 'multi454fasta.manip.r'  is correct (I already checked with the  'find' command).

I also tried to move the script into the home directory `/home/genethongandolfi/scripts` and the error message changes: the job runs because the system finds the script, but not the input file in the usual path `/data/users/genethongandolfi/analysis/etc...` . It seems to be something for which the `/data/users/...` path is not recognized when I launch a job.

Comment: is `/data` an NFS mount? What user runs the script?

Comment: Maybe `qsub` runs the command on a different host?

Comment: Does **every node** have the data file in this location? It's not enough if the data is available on the master node.

Comment: Yeh, you're right, actually I started to suppose that data are stored only on the master and not on the slave nodes. I have to verify it, thanks!

Comment: Getting a similar error. Did you ever fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons why this could be the case:

1. The file location on the slave node is different from the master
2. The file permissions on the slave do not permit access to the file

If you can, try logging into the slave node, change to the user running the job, and check the file location and permissions.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the information and comments! I will try with it and let you know!

Answer (score -1):

Had the same error for a simple c program in form of an .exe

Removing the .exe from the shell script did eventually fix it.

So instead of ./program.exe write ./program